# Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler dependency issue with Asp.Net5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I am getting the below error when i am trying to do a simple application using 
ASP.NET 5 RC1. Kindly help me with the issue. Not sure, where i am making the mistake :( Kindly do the needful. Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

[image: IISHandler Dependency Error]
**Project.json**

```
{
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"      
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {  }
     }
  },
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "webroot": "wwwroot"
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;

namespace MVA5
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            // Add the platform handler to the request pipeline.
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{ 
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

**DNVM List**

[image: dnvm list]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 target frameworks(TFMs or target framework monikers) listed in your `project.json`: `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`. So when you do a build, its built for both of these frameworks.

Now since you have the dependency of `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"` listed only as part of `dnx451`, when doing a build for `dnxcore50` the build is failing (I agree that from error list may be its not very clear).

Try moving both the `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core"` and `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"` dependencies to the `dependencies` node common to both the TFMs and then do a build.

Comment: Thank you after move all the dependencies as common dependency it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use 1.0.0-rc1-final runtime.

For that type into console: `dnvm list` 
If you don't use 1.0.0-rc1-final runtime, type into console: dnvm upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. I was targetting my runtime as beta 8 and changed to rc1-final.